# PiecewiseExpand doesn't take all kind of assumptions

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, assumptions, piecewise

Running PiecewiseExpand[expr, assum] does not work with all kind of assumptions.
For example, the following line will not split the expression with absolute values in the chambers, considering m1=m2.
Why is it so?
How can I allow arbitrary asumptions, in particular setting some of the entries equal to others, and some greater than others?

```
PiecewiseExpand[-Abs[m1 - m2] - Abs[m2 - m3] - Abs[m1 - m3] + 
   n/2*(Abs[m1] + Abs[m2] + Abs[m3]), {m1 \[Element] Reals, 
   m2 \[Element] Reals, m3 \[Element] Reals, 
   m1 == m2 >= m3}] // FullSimplify
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this what you're after?

```
Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[-Abs[m1 - m2] - Abs[m2 - m3] - Abs[m1 - m3] +
    n/2*(Abs[m1] + Abs[m2] + Abs[m3]), {m1 == m2, m2 >= m3}, 
  Reals], {m1 == m2, m2 >= m3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems nice and simple.